# retrofit -parse data with unknown types

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm consuming an API where the data response comes like this :

```
[{"status":"5"},{"status":["5","2"]},{"status":null}]
```

So I'm using retrofit and this is my response model :

```
public class ResponseModel
{
    private String status;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

}
```

But I didn't know how the response model should be because as you see the same JSON property("status") can come as a string or as an array.

I didn't know how I should do this, hope you can help me with it, appreciate any help!

Comment: Did you try keeping generic data type like ```Object```? And then you may have to type cast while using.